# Вывод всех фоновых процессов

Tags: c

Подскажите, как на языке C по нажатию на кнопку вывести все процессы, которые выполняются в фоновом режиме ?(в qtdesighner для Linux)

Comment: Что понимается под "фоновым процессом" и для какой ОС?

Comment: Linux. А вот что понимается под фоновым процессом я не знаю. Написано "получить все процессы выполняющиеся в фоновом режиме"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, с помощью [ps](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?category=1&russian=5&topic=ps) и [popen()](http://www.opennet.ru/cgi-bin/opennet/man.cgi?topic=popen):

```
FILE *ps = popen( "/bin/ps [подставить нужные аргументы]", "r" );
/* читаем и парсим вывод ps */
```